# windows phone handle orientation change

Tags: windows-phone-7

how to handle orientation change event inside a usercontrol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend against having your control worry about the orientation it is being displayed in. This should be the concern of the page the control is contained in, not the actual control. You want to avoid the situation where the two are fighting fo determining how something should be displayed.

Try and write your control so that it work regardless of the page orientation. If you can't do that make 2 versions of the control and let the page decide which one to show based on orientation.